# Get Claims from Extended UserClaim Table in Web Api using Microsoft Identity

Tags: claims-based-identity

i am working on ASP.Net 5 , web api project and using Microsoft Identity and jwt token based for my security management . I have already extended the user claim table and add a new row of `isSelected` to this table . I need to know , how can i just get the claims that has the `isSelected == true` from the table , is there any way that i can use the `_signinManager` services for this task? I can do like this for normal situation :

```
var claims = await _signinManager.ClaimsFactory.CreateAsync(user)
```

and get the `ClaimPrincipals` , but this will return all the claims whether the `isSelected` is `true` or `false` .

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Some behaviors require customization. Like in your case, you want the default configuration to filter list of data based on a particular column name (`isSelected`) and only return the filtered list. The best way to approach this using a customized `UserManager` or `SignInManager` and create a method that will do just what you're asking for.

Here's an idea:
Create a method called `IList<UserClaim> GetUserClaimsBasedOnSelection(bool isSelected, User user)`. All that this method should do is use the underlying Claims retrieving method and just filter that list to only return the selected claims. That's it. And then after you just register your configured `SignInManager` inside `Program.cs` or `startup.cs` by adding this service to your `AddIdentity` service configuration `.AddSignInManager<YourSignInManager>()`